# invalid syntax on Quote from person in python

Tags: python, quote, sentence

hello I'm learning python. I want to use Quote from person in my Sentence but I see this Error. How can I solve it?
I write my code down line:

```
sentence='shiva said:'I am\n programmer''
print(sentence)
```

and my Error is: invalid syntax

Answer (score 1):

Strings in Python can use double quotes or single quotes.  If you want single quotes in the sentence you can use double quotes:

```
sentence = "shiva said:'I am\n programmer'"
```

You can also just escape the single quotes by preceding with a backslash.  This tells Python to not treat the following single quote as the end of the string.

```
sentence = 'shiva said:\'I am\n programmer\''
```

Triple quotes are also available (both types) and can span multiple lines:

```
sentence = """shiva said 'I am
programmer'"""
```